# Search User within multiple SharePoint Group using ClientPeoplePickerWebServiceInterface.ClientPeoplePickerSearchUser()

Tags: sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app, csom

I have created a People Picker control for SP Hosted App using CSOM and below API

```
ClientPeoplePickerWebServiceInterface.ClientPeoplePickerSearchUser
```

I have to search for user within multiple SharePoint custom group , i know we can narrow our search to a SP group using below property

```
ClientPeoplePickerQueryParameters querryParams = new ClientPeoplePickerQueryParameters();
querryParams.SharePointGroupID = 13;//where 13 is the ID value for the custom SharePoint group
```

Now I have to search user within multiple group but SharePointGroupID  property takes only one group id. How can i achieve my requirement for search within multiple group.

Answer (score 3):

You can ignore `SharePointGroupID` and include `PrincipalSource`. In `SharePointGroupID`, you can provide only one group. Value of `PrincipalSource` can be

15: Choices are  All

4: Membership Provider

8: RoleProvider

1: UserInfoList

2: Windows

> These values can be combined

I have a [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1008871/Developing-Custom-Date-Picker-People-Picker-and-Ch) for building custom people picker.

```
var data = {
    queryParams: {
        __metadata: {
            type: 'SP.UI.ApplicationPages.ClientPeoplePickerQueryParameters'
        },
        AllowEmailAddresses: true, //This is for the people picker control  
            //and allows valid email addresses to be resolved and used as values
        AllowMultipleEntities: false, //This for the people picker control 
            //and allows for entering multiple users or groups
        AllUrlZones: false, //Only affects the search if you have set the WebApplicationID. 
            //It search across all UrlZones for that particular web application
        MaximumEntitySuggestions: 50, //Basically a row limit of how many users or groups are returned
        PrincipalSource: 15, //What sources you wish to search. Choices are  All - 15 , 
            //Membership Provider - 4 , RoleProvider - 8, 
            //UserInfoList - 1  or Windows - 2. These values can be combined
        PrincipalType: 15, //Controls the type of entities that are returned in the results. 
            //Choices are All - 15, Distribution List - 2 , Security Groups - 4,  
            //SharePoint Groups &ndash; 8, User &ndash; 1. These values can be combined
        QueryString: "Your search string" //The term to search
        Required: false, //This is for the people picker control and makes the field required. 
            //It has no effect on the search
        SharePointGroupID: null, //An integer representing the group ID you want to limit your search to. 
            //Only works if you set the Web parameter also which cannot be done via REST
        UrlZone: null, // Limits the search to certain zones within the web application. 
            //Can only be used if the UrlZoneSpecified  parameter is set to true. 
            //Choices are Custom - 3, Default - 0, Extranet - 4, Internet &ndash; 2, 
            //IntraNet &ndash; 1. These values can be combined
        UrlZoneSpecified: false, //Sets whether you are limiting your search 
            //to a particular URL zone in the web application.
        Web: null, //If set it works in conjunction with the SharePointGroupID parameter.
        WebApplicationID: null //String value representing the Guid 
            //of the web application you want to limit your search to
    }
}
```

Comment: But i have to pick users from those SharePoint groups not from entire Source as you told. Example : user1 is available Within All source, but user1 is not a member of SP group1 or group 2, so in that case user1 should not come as a suggestion

Comment: In that case, you will not be able to use this ClientPeoplePicker. Result sources are fixed for this control. You have to look for another end point and another solution.

Comment: I need one more input , if i add a AD group to my SP custom group and that AD group having users user1, user2, user3. Now if i search for user1 within that SP custom group my serach result not returning that user info but if i serach for that AD group i am able to get the group , properties has been set like below   querryParams.PrincipalSource = PrincipalSource.All;
                querryParams.PrincipalType = PrincipalType.All; //(PrincipalType)principalType;